# How can I switch multiple lines using a single switch?

Tags: switches

I am looking to make a switchbox for my 34 pin floppy drive (I know you can't hotswap) but I don't know what to use. I have heard of a multiplexer but I think it is only one way. I need to be able to switch the single "B" line from a DOS computer between a 5.25" floppy drive, and a floppy drive emulator. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's a "B" line?

Comment: The title of your question reads `multiple lines`, but the body reads `the single "B" line`. Which is it?

Comment: examine a floppy drive cable for dual drives ... only part of the cable is switched between drives A: and B:

Comment: Apologies, the B line is actually a set of 34 pins/lines, I very stupidly added the B thinking that people would know what I am talking about, because I am trying to connect two floppy drives to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may actually be able to do a lot better than having to switch 34 wires.  Take a look at the floppy connector pinout:

http://www.interfacebus.com/PC_Floppy_Drive_PinOut.html

First of all, half of the wires are grounds, which you can just connect in parallel.  Secondly, the cabling is actually designed for two drives to share the same cable, with a 'twist' in the cable to differentiate between the drives and all of the other connections wired in parallel.  What goes through the twist are the drive select and motor enable signals.  You might be able to get away with a simple DPDT switch to decide which drive gets connected to the drive select and motor enable signals, and connect all of the other signals to both drives.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to switch Motor Enable and Drive Select for B drive, so that's only two pins.